# Restrict Table to be on left column of the page

Tags: tables

I am working on a document with a two column structure, Currently my right side column is empty and the table on my left column is spilling to the right column. How can I restrict table to be on the left side column.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}r}
Algorithm              & Experts(RMSLE) & Benchmark(RMSLE) \\
\hline
Random Forest & 3.013653 & 3.056084 \\
GBM            & 2.888076 & 2.081570 \\
SVM(SVR)           & 2.979915 & 3.056084 \\
\end{tabular}

\caption{Experts and Non-expert Prediction}
\label{tab:expert_table}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting `small` font size for table and removing/adjusting table column separation:

[image]

## Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} %% <---------adjust the value here
\small
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}lcr@{}}
Algorithm              & Experts(RMSLE) & Benchmark(RMSLE) \\
\hline
Random Forest & 3.013653 & 3.056084 \\
GBM            & 2.888076 & 2.081570 \\
SVM(SVR)           & 2.979915 & 3.056084 \\
\end{tabular}

\caption{Experts and Non-expert Prediction}
\label{tab:expert_table}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```